# Crear Pixmap de X11 sin ventana

Tags: c++, c

A la función

```
cairo_surface_t * cairo_xlib_surface_create 
(Display *dpy, Drawable drawable, Visual *visual, 
int width, int height);
```

Necesito proporcionarle un `Drawtable`. No tengo interés en que el `Drawtable` se visualice, por lo que tengo entendido que necesito que el `Drawtable` debe ser un `Pixmap` en lugar de un `Window`

El problema es que para crear un `Pixmap` tambien necesito un `Drawtable`, por lo que parece que la única forma de obtener un `Drawtable` es creando una ventana:

```
Pixmap XCreatePixmap(display, drawable, width, height, depth)
```

¿Hay alguna forma de llamar a la primera función (`cairo_xlib_surface_create`) sin haber creado una ventana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la [documentación de Image Surfaces](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html) puedes renderizar a búferes de memoria con las funciones:

1. > ```
   > cairo_surface_t*    cairo_image_surface_create          (cairo_format_t format,
   >                                                          int width,
   >                                                          int height);
   > ```
   >
   > Crea una imagen surface con el formato y dimensiones especificados. El contenido inicial de la surface no está definido; deberás limpiar el búfer explícitamente usando, por ejemplo, [`cairo_rectangle()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-Paths.html#cairo-rectangle) y [`cairo_fill()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-fill) si lo quieres limpiar.
   >
   > - *format*: formato de los pixeles de la superficie a crear.
   > - *width*: ancho de la superficie, en pixeles.
   > - *height*: altura de la superficie, en pixeles.
   > - *Retorno*: un puntero a la surface recién creada. El llamador es el propietario de la surface y debe llamar a `cairo_surface_destroy` cuando no la necesite más. Esta función siempre devuelve un puntero válido, pero devolverá un puntero a una superficie nula (`"nil"`) si un error como memoria insuficiente sucede. Puedes usar [`cairo_surface_status()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-cairo-surface-t.html#cairo-surface-status).
2. > ```
   > cairo_surface_t*    cairo_image_surface_create_for_data (unsigned char *data,
   >                                                          cairo_format_t format,
   >                                                          int width,
   >                                                          int height,
   >                                                          int stride);
   > ```
   >
   > Crea una imagen surface con los datos de pixel proveídos. El buúfer resultante debe ser conservado hasta que [`cairo_surface_t`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-cairo-surface-t.html#cairo-surface-t) sea destruido o se llame [`cairo_surface_finish()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-cairo-surface-t.html#cairo-surface-finish) sobre la surface. Los contenidos iniciales del búfer se usarán como el contenido inicial de la imagen; deberás limpiar el búfer explícitamente usando, por ejemplo, [`cairo_rectangle()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-Paths.html#cairo-rectangle) y [`cairo_fill()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-fill) si lo quieres limpiar.
   >
   > - *data*: un puntero a una superficie proporcionada por la aplicación en que escribir datos.
   > - *format*: formato de los pixeles en el búfer.
   > - *width*: ancho de la superficie, en pixeles.
   > - *height*: altura de la superficie, en pixeles.
   > - *stride*: cantidad de bytes entre el inicio de las filas en el búfer. Tener este dato separado del ancho permite añadir un padding al final de las filas, o para escribir una subporción de una imagen mayor.
   > - *Retorno*: un puntero a la surface recién creada. El llamador es el propietario de la surface y debe llamar a `cairo_surface_destroy` cuando no la necesite más. Esta función siempre devuelve un puntero válido, pero devolverá un puntero a una superficie nula (`"nil"`) si un error como memoria insuficiente sucede. Puedes usar [`cairo_surface_status()`](https://www.cairographics.org/manual-1.0.2/cairo-cairo-surface-t.html#cairo-surface-status).

Ambas opciones permiten renderizar en memoria en lugar de en una ventana y no tienen dependencia sobre `Drawable`, la segunda opción incluso permite proporcionar un búfer sobre el que escribir.